# Convert TXT unordered to csv

Tags: csv, awk, sed

Currently I have the following text file, which is the dump of a website

```
    [61] Title1 
    subtitle1 
    1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812 
    Phone: (00) 0000 0000 [62] Email 

    [61] Title2 
    Subtitle2 
    1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812 
    Phone: (00) 0000 0000 [65] Email [66] Website 


    62 mailto: info@yyyyyyyyyy.com 
    65 mailto: mitchellstccc@xxxxxx.com 
    66 http://www.website.com
```

I need to convert a csv file, but replace email as the values ​​below email and website, if available.

```
    Title1, subtitle1, 1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812, (00) 0000 0000, Email
    Title2, subtitle2, 1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812, (00) 0000 0000, Email, http://www.website.com
```

How can I accomplish this task?

I am trying to use awk, but my awk-fu sucks. 
They can give me a hand? (I have no preference for scripting or programming language)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a GNU bash, GNU grep and GNU sed?

Comment: Helo Cyrus. Yes, I have it. I have access to CentOS, Ubuntu and Slackware. All of them in last stables versions

Comment: Where are the emails in the output?

Comment: @TomFenech, sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: In the output, the lines just say "Email", should that be replaced with the email addresses from the input?

Comment: By the way, I think you really need to give this a go yourself and highlight a particular problem that you're having. That way, people will be more inclined to help you out. At the moment, the question is pretty much "Can someone write me a script please?", rather than "I've written this but it doesn't work, how can I do X?".

Comment: Did you read that English is not my native language? Is a little hard to explain something that I dont know. 

Ok. I'll try to make better questions

Comment: You should edit this question to show what you have attempted and what is not working. Also show exactly what the input and desired output look like. Do all the lines start with blank space? Should the email address be in the output? Once you've done that, people will be happy to help you.

Comment: I agree with everything @TomFenech said but I posted an answer anyway as I think just figuring out what it does will be a good learning experience for the OP and I dont think a beginner in awk would get close to a solution without a lot more interaction/help than is reasonable to expect us to provide in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in 2 passes, something like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++
    RS = ""; FS = "\n"
}
NR==FNR {
    if (/^[[:digit:]]/) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            key = val = $i
            sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",key)
            sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
            gsub(/ /,"",val)
            map["["key"]"] = val
        }
    }
    next
}
!/^[[:digit:]]/ {
    out = ""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        out = out sprintf("%s", (i>1?",":""))
        split($i,arr,/[[:space:]]+/)
        for (j=1;j in arr;j++) {
            if (arr[j] ~ /^\[.*\]$/) {
                if (arr[j] in map) {
                    arr[j+1] = map[arr[j]]
                    arr[j] = ","
                }
                else {
                    arr[j] = ""
                }
            }
            out = out sprintf("%s%s", (j>1?" ":""), arr[j])
        }
    }
    gsub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,", ",out)
    print out
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
 Title1, subtitle1, 1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812, Phone: (00) 0000 0000, mailto:info@yyyyyyyyyy.com
 Title2, Subtitle2, 1428 Elm Street, Springwood, Ohio 0812, Phone: (00) 0000 0000, mailto:mitchellstccc@xxxxxx.com, http://www.website.com
```

The first pass only reads the mapping of numbers to email and site values, the 2nd pass only processes the blocks of addresses replacing `[66] Website` with the value for `66` read in the first pass.